# Subtracting multiple vectors from each row of an array (super broadcasting)

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization, bsxfun

I have a data set, `X` that is `m x 2`, and three vectors stored in a matrix `C = [c1'; c2'; c3']` that is `3 x 2`. I am trying to vectorize my code that finds, for each data point in `X`, which vector in `C` is closest (squared distance). I would like to subtract each vector (row) in `C` from each vector (row) in `X`, resulting in an `m x 6` or `3m x 2` matrix of differences between the elements of `X` and the elements of `C`. My current implementation does this one row in `X` at a time:

```
for i = 1:size(X, 1)
    diffs = bsxfun(@minus, X(i,:), C);    % gives a 3 x 2 matrix result
    [~, idx(i)] = min(sumsq(diffs), 2);   % returns the index of the closest vector
                                          % in C to the ith vector in X
end
```

I want to get rid of this `for` loop and just vectorize the whole thing, but `bsxfun(@minus, X, C)` gives me a an error in Octave:

> error: bsxfun: nonconformant dimensions: 300x2 and 3x2

Any ideas how I can "super-broadcast" my subtraction operation between these two matrices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core of this problem is to compute a distance matrix `D` of size `m x 3` that contains the pairwise distances between all data points in `X` and all data points in `C`. The Euclidean distance between the i-th vector `x_i` in `X` and the j-th vector `c_j` in `C` can be rewritten as:

```
|x_i-c_j|^2 = |x_i|^2 - 2<x_i, c_j> + |c_j|^2
```

where <,> refers to inner product. The right-hand side of this equation can be easily vectorized, because the inner product of all pairs is just `X * C'` which is BLAS3 operation. This way of computing the distance matrix is known as `dist2` function in the book Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop. I copy the function below with a little modification.

```
function D = dist2(X, C)        
    tempx = full(sum(X.^2, 2));
    tempc = full(sum(C.^2, 2).');
    D = -2*(X * C.'）;
    D = bsxfun(@plus, D, tempx);
    D = bsxfun(@plus, D, tempc);
```

The `full` here is used in case `X` or `C` is a sparse matrix.

Note: The distance matrix `D` computed this way might have tiny negative entries due to numerical rounding error. To guard against this case, use

```
D = max(D, 0);
```

The indices of the closest vector in `C` can be retrieved from `D`:

```
[~, idx] = min(D, [], 2);
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a good way of avoiding making temp variables in the event that my data set is very large? Would doing so slow down the execution? I am using this for a K means algorithm, so it has to call it fairly frequently.

Comment: This is great. I tested it out and it definitely speeds up execution. Thanks a lot! Now I just have to figure out how to do a similar vectorization for finding the mean of all points closest to each of the centroids in my `C` matrix. That loop only executes once for each vector in `C`, which is usually a much smaller number than for `X`.

Comment: @Engineero: Look at his [webpage](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~dkuang3/software/kmeans3.html) -- I think you'll find it interesting :)

Comment: Good call, that's a great project! Mind if I try to port it to Octave? I haven't looked at the files much yet, but I imagine it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: @Engineero Glad to know you find it useful. It will be awesome if you port it to Octave. I guess the main hassle will be handling the parameters without those `statset` calls which are only available in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the statistics toolbox, you can use `pdist2`:

> PDIST2 Pairwise distance between two sets of observations.
>       D = PDIST2(X,Y) returns a matrix D containing the Euclidean distances
>       between each pair of observations in the MX-by-N data matrix X and
>       MY-by-N data matrix Y.

So in your case,

```
[~, which_C] = min(pdist2(X,C), [], 2);
```

is what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you could use this beauty:

```
[~, which_c] = min(sum(bsxfun(@minus, X, permute(C, [3 2 1])).^2, 2), [], 3);
```

which wouldn't win any prizes for readability, robustness or manageability, but you will gain some speed (and the need for a toolbox, mind you :)

Comment: If you see the implementation of `pdist` for Euclidean distance, you will see it's not vectorized.

Comment: @DaKuang: did you time the execution time for both methods? My guess is that it's not going to be much different (provided you have JIT enabled)...

Comment: Here is my timing result: For `X` of size `10000x10000` and `C` of size `20x10000`, `dist2` takes 0.35 sec, `pdist2` takes 2.30 sec, and your last line of code takes 1.25 sec.

Comment: @DaKuang: Allright, you can have my vote :) (I got an out of memory error for my method)

Comment: @DaKuang: Still, I think what my first method adds is readability. If you need to do this only a few times, the speed is not that much of an issue (...still pondering over how inefficient operations on 3D arrays are in MATLAB...)

Comment: Rody, are you referring to `pdist2`? Yes it is definitely more readable but you can also save the `dist2` function into a file and call `[~, which_C] = min(dist2(X,C), [], 2);`. In my experience, the stats toolbox is really slow in evaluating pairwise Euclidean distances. If you are interested, I will self-advertise and direct you to my [webpage](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~dkuang3/software/kmeans3.html) :) for a timing comparison of K-means.

Comment: I suspect the mathworks dealt with the burden of backwards compatibility by avoiding bsxfun. To also keep memory usage low, they are forced to use slow code... Well, that's my guess anyway :) why not post your kmeans and pdist2 on the Mathworks file exchange?