# Find the closest weight vector to each instance in the data matrix

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, bigdata, gpu

Suppose I have a weight matrix `W` **nxm** where m is the number of variables and the n is the number of instances. Also I have data matrix `X` of the same size. I try to find the closest weight vector to each instance in X. However both matrices are so dimensional therefore plain methods are not sufficient enough. I have tried some GPU trick at MATLAB but it does not work well since it was sequential approach that was calculating the closest weight for each instance sequentially. I am now looking for efficient one shot code. That takes all the W and X and find the winner with some MATLAB tricks with possibly some GPU addition. Is there any one that can suggest any code snippet in the MATLAB?

This is the thing that I wrote for sequential

```
        x_in_d = gpuArray(x_in); % take input instance to device
        W_d = gpuArray(W); % take weight matrix to device
        Dx = W_d - x_in_d(ones(size(W_d,1),1),logical(ones(1,length(x_in_d))));
        [d_min,winner] = min(sum((Dx.^2)'));
        d_min = gather(d_min); %gather results
        winner = gather(winner);
```

Comment: Could you give your "inefficient code" - the one that works but is too slow? It will be much easier for us to give you an efficient version of that - your description takes quite a bit of parsing...

Comment: Related (if not identical): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178500/subtracting-multiple-vectors-from-each-row-of-an-array-super-broadcasting/17179270#comment24877254_17179270

Comment: If `n` and `m` are large, the simple act of moving all the stuff to the GPU and back may take more time than the whole CPU calculation would; this is one of the most encountered pitfalls in GPGPU. Unless you post the basics of your problem and your attempted solutions, we can't really help you.

Comment: If that is indeed what he is asking for, still not sure I interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by so dimensional? It's just an m x n matrix right?

It would be really helpful if you could provide some sample data, based off your description (which isn't the clearest), here is what I think your data looks like.

weights=

[1 4 2

5 3 1]

data=

[2 5 1

1 2 2]

And you want to figure out which row of weights is closest to the row of data? Which in this case would be the first row of weights for both rows of data.

Please edit your question to clarify what your asking for and consider using some examples.

EDIT:

I like Rody's Dup. Comment, if I am correct, check out: [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178500/subtracting-multiple-vectors-from-each-row-of-an-array-super-broadcasting/17179270#comment24877254_17179270)

Comment: here is what I mean with dimensional too big n x too big m and as I said data and weight are in matrix form not vector form so it is not a single line data and weight

Comment: Look at my answer now, when I editted my answer, it removed the linebreaks and made them vectors instead of matrices, sorry about that

Comment: I get the answer you added, and Bishop's code works really well. Thanks for notice :)

Comment: Do you think writing a mex file at c++ makes the process faster, or worth to the time consumed ??

Comment: If you have a huge matrix like you are implying, yes, definitely.